# Is it possible to just deny download from TCP/IP?

Tags: download, blocking, tcpip

I want to deny my Internet connection's download properties for all ports. I mean I want to only allow upload. Is it possible?

Comment: please clarify what you're trying to accomplish.  do you have some server on your network that you're trying to make "upload-only"?  are you trying to restrict other users on your network?  are you trying to restrict all outgoing traffic while allowing incoming traffic?  your question as stated now doesn't make much sense.

Comment: At least you should specify what operating system or networking device are you configuring.

Comment: If you're talking from purely networking terms, you have to be careful -- upload/download is really just egress/ingress...and both directions are required to perform a TCP handshake. Completely blocking one direction or the other will break all connectivity using TCP connections.

Answer (score 3):

`iptables -I OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j REJECT`?

It will block all outgoing connections in Linux.

```
iptables -A INPUT -m quota --quota 2000000 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -j REJECT
```

It will setup "download" quota to 2000000 bytes. Note that uploads will also slightly decrease the counter.

Comment: hi quack and Vi. clearly, i want to share my internet connection on my network and users can make only upload to everywhere on my network. if i have to use server or app for this, i can use. my preference is windows about OS. thank you for interest.

Comment: so i want to block download everyhere at the same time.

Comment: What do you mean by "upload" and "download"? FTP uploads? BitTorrent? There are many protocols with upload capability. Do you want to block only big downloads (like movies) or any of them? Is IRC/Jabber/ICQ message retrieval considered "download" and message sending considered "upload"? How securely do you want to block "downloads"?

Comment: i mean deny every port of download, allow every port of upload.

Comment: What is "download" and what is "upload"? Should it really done on TCP/IP level? TCP or IP don't know what is happening, upload or download. Or you want to detect download by prevalence of traffic in one direction?

Comment: Download mean is "incoming". Upload mean is "outgoing" traffic. i want to block big requests all ports of incoming traffic. outgoing traffic can be free. my internet connection is limited and internet conection cost calculate upload + downoad data's total. i hope this explain is clear.

Comment: @Kerberos: blocking all "incoming" traffic would block transmissions necessary for proper operation of "outgoing" traffic (eg, ACK packets and the like).

Comment: @Kerberos: You probably want to setup quotas for upload and download, e.g, user may send packets to internet, but receive only 1 megabyte of packets per hour. But if user attempts to download something big, the quota will be exhausted, and user will lost capability of both downloading and uploading.
Each dowload has a bit of upload, and each upload has a bit of upload. If you fully close the one direction, you will not be able to upload or download at all.

Comment: i understood what you told me. thank very much for your help and instruction. May it be easy.

Comment: i want to ask one more thing. if i use connectify (www.connectify.me) on win 7 and share internet to other users. how can i only access ftp to other users who they connect to internet over on my win 7 with connectify. which firewall or system app suggest me?

Comment: @Kerberos: Don't know much about Windows firewall (although experimented a lot with them 3-5 years ago), but Kerio Winrounte Firewall looks rather advanced to have all these features. You should also consider setting up proxies to allow users to access internet through the your host at level higher that TCP/IP. It will be more controllable.

Comment: Vi, i spent your time. thank you very much for your help.